# How to Stop an Application.Ontime Loop in VBA with a Stop Button

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have 2 Command Buttons, MarketOpen and MarketClosed in Excel.

When MarketOpen is clicked the following loop occurs:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MarketOpen
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Marketclosed
End Sub

Sub MarketOpen()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "RefreshStocks"
End Sub

Sub RefreshStocks()
Application.CalculateFull
MarketOpen
End Sub
```

I have tried to end the loop with

```
Sub MarketClosed()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "RefreshStocks", , False
End Sub
```

However, I am getting a run-time error '1004':

Method 'Ontime' of Object' _Application' failed.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see the official help from Microsoft for [`OnTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx). vtc: OffTopic - Find Tutorial

Comment: or set a global boolean flag, and stop button sets it to false...